# Python colored text to the terminal

Tags: python, terminal, output, ansi-colors

We can set color text or foreground color text in the terminal in Python. I have gone through this **SO's** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/287944/5929910). Some of the example color code is here

```
class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[96m'

print(f"{bcolors.OKGREEN}Yes we can set any Hex color in terminal?{bcolors.ENDC}")
```

Everything is okay. But you may be noticed we have a few color codes to set. After the digging drive, I found some other color code source from **Microsoft** [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences?redirectedfrom=MSDN#text-formatting). I have two of my questions here.

- What does the mean of the code like `BOLD = '\033[1m'` (pattern means)?
- Can we convert/use any Hex color code in the terminal?
  the color source is limited so, can we use any hex code in the terminal?

Comment: [Wiki has an excellent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) article.  Personally, I reference this page a lot.  It also provides the escape sequences and colours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [ANSI Escape Codes](https://tforgione.fr/posts/ansi-escape-codes/)

ANSI escape codes allow you to do plenty of beautiful things in the terminal. You can change the color of the font, font style (bold, italic, underlined, etc...), and you can also move the cursor to overwrite previous text, to make text change dynamically.

**Building codes**

Basically, the codes are built like this:

```
\033[XXXm
```

where `XXX` is a series of semicolon-separated parameters.

- they start with `\033[` (or any of the codes specified above + [)
- then, the contain an arbitrary number of integers separated by ;
- and they end with m

The code containing only 0 (being \x1B[0m) will reset any style property of the font.

Most of the time, you will print a code changing the style of your terminal, then print a certain string, and then, the reset code.

Here are the codes that you can use to change the color of the font, or the color of the background.

```
| Color                                  | Font code        | Background code  |
|----------------------------------------|------------------|------------------|
| Black                                  | \x1B[30m         | \x1B[40m         |
| Red                                    | \x1B[31m         | \x1B[41m         |
| Green                                  | \x1B[32m         | \x1B[42m         |
| Yellow                                 | \x1B[33m         | \x1B[43m         |
| Blue                                   | \x1B[34m         | \x1B[44m         |
| Magenta                                | \x1B[35m         | \x1B[45m         |
| Cyan                                   | \x1B[36m         | \x1B[46m         |
| White                                  | \x1B[37m         | \x1B[47m         |
| Any palette color (with V in [0-255])  | \x1B[38;5;Vm     | \x1B[48;5;Vm     |
| Any RGB color (with values in [0-255]) | \x1B[38;2;R;G;Bm | \x1B[48;2;R;G;Bm |
```

- [List of ANSI color escape sequences](https://gist.github.com/vratiu/9780109)
- [Build your own Command-Line with ANSI escape codes](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing here with **ANSI escape codes**.

All follow the pattern `\033[XXXm`. You can have multiple instructions related to that, not only the one you listed.

For color codes in terminals, it depends of the system. The most basic terminals have a set of 8 different colors:

- Black: \u001b[30m
- Red: \u001b[31m
- Green: \u001b[32m
- Yellow: \u001b[33m
- Blue: \u001b[34m
- Magenta: \u001b[35m
- Cyan: \u001b[36m
- White: \u001b[37m
- Reset: \u001b[0m

Comment: Got the fixed point but i am looking for additional way to set **hex** color.